# get localstorage value and put in textbox angulars

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

i have a textbox called `item` and when the page loads i want to get a value from the `localstorage` and put it in the textbox `item` which i later send to the database.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="newitem_ctrl">
  <input name="item" type="text" id="item" placeholder="Name of Item" ng-model="item" required="required">
</div>
```

JS:

```js
.controller('newitem_ctrl', function($scope,$http,$location,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup, $timeout){
  $scope.item = localStorage.getItem("shop_id")

  $scope.insertnew = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Adding...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
    event.preventDefault();
    $http.post("http://localhost/myweb/insert.php",
    {'item':$scope.item,'quantity'})
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
      console.log(data)
      {$ionicLoading.hide();}
    }).error(function(error){
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: change `console.log(data)` to `$scope.item = data.foo`; or what ever your item text is.. and remove those curlys from `{$ionicLoading.hide();}`

Comment: Please review [ask]. There is a lot of detail missing from question. You haven't identified a specific problem or even asked a question